# Some questions about presentation of First-Order Logic in a book by Raymond Smullyan

Tags: logic

I'm re-reading Raymond Smullyan, *First Order-Logic* (1968 - Dover reprint).

It's a wonderful booklet (I liked it very much), but a little bit terse.

It uses the distinction between *individual variables* (to be used "bound") and *individual parameters* (to be used "free") [pag.43].

**Question 1)** I think that this (now) uncommon usage dates back to Hilbert & Bernays' *Grundlagen der Mathematik* (1934) : is it true ?

The book uses concepts of f-o semantic quite similar to current "model theory" ones, like *first order valuation*; but, if I'm right, he do not introduce a concept of "logical consequence" (for f-o logic; he uses only *truth-functional consequence* - pag.12).

**Question 2)** Why this concept is missing ? It is also missing form J.L.Bell & A.B.Slomson, *Models and Ultraproducts* (1969): when "logical consequence" has become *standard* in textbooks exposition of f-o logic ?

He uses the concept of *formula with constants in* $U$ (or $U$-*formulas*), where $U$ is a non-empty set called *universe of individuals* [pag.46]. He substitute individuals for free variables [i.e.$F(k/x)$ for any $k \in U$].

**Question 3)** May we say that should be better to use names for individuals (like the *numeral* $\overline{n}$ for $n$) so that, for any $k \in U$, we can make the substitution $F(\overline{k}/x)$ ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ad qn 1**: This usage, typographically distinguishing free variables (parameters) from bound variables is certainly also in Gentzen's doctoral thesis, published in 1934. I don't know which way round the influence, in any, was between  Bernays and his (nominal) student Gentzen here. The usage is inherited by Dag Prawitz's hugely influential *Natural Deduction* of 1965, and  the usage in fact then remains not uncommon in those whose logical work is more proof-theoretically orientated.

**Ad qn 2** I don't *think* anything deep is going on here. Chap. 1 on prop. logic has already explored the relations between $A$'s being a logical consequence of the set $X$, the unsatisfiability of the set $X, \neg A$, (via compactness) the unsatisfiability of a finite subset of $X, \neg A$, and the deducibility of $A$ from $X$. Maybe Smullyan didn't think he needed to go through *all* this again in the first-order case: it is enough to talk about the (un)satisfiability of sets of wffs, compactness, and deducibility again. But yes, perhaps surprising not to define outright logical consequence for first-order wffs.

**Ad qn 3** No we can't say that. The point is that the number of elements in the universe can outstrip the number of names -- for names (or terms more generally) are denumerable for Smullyan, but the elements of the universe U might be uncountable, so there are nameless elements.

Comment: Thanks. I have only an electronic copy of the translation by C.P.Wirth of Volume I of *Hilbert & Bernays* (2nd ed - 1968); pag.98 : "To mark the difference between bound and free variables explicitly, we will use letters from the beginning and the middle of the alphabet $a, b, c, m, n, r, s$,
for the free individual variables, and the last letters of the alphabet $u, v, w, x, y, z$ for the bound variables." But I have no copy of the 1st ed (and I'm not able to read german): so I'm guessing that it was already there ...